# How to get a node which is before other?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<movies>
<movie>
    <title>A History of Violence</title>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Heat</title>     
</movie>
</movies>
```

And I want to get first movie but saying that bring me the movie that is before `Heat`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good use case for [`preceding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding):

```
//movie/title[. = "Heat"]/preceding::movie
```

Or, [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling):

```
//movie[title = "Heat"]/preceding-sibling::movie
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have another problem...
Your solution bring me all movies before, how to do it if you want to get just a movie before, only one?

Comment: @SergioM. sure just add the `[1]` to the end of the expression.